# Would appreciate some assistance finding StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, stringindexoutofbounds

This program is the String of 3 numbers then 7 letters to be transformed into its equivalent number using methods 
The user input is a string which is changed from letters to digits and back into a string of numbers separated by dashes.
So this is only week 3ish of learning and i got tripped up by methods. The error code I am receiving is telling me the string index is out of bounds. So, i suspect the error is in my conversion or where i concatenated the strings at the end around line 89. I spent 20 min with the TA and would appreciate any guidance. I still have more to do with the program so i am omitting some of it because I would only like help when i come to a place that I become stuck for more than 45 min.MAIN QUESTION- Where does the error occur and why?
I attempted to put print statements everywhere to see what was happening... however I may be stuck in a loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConvPhoneNumTwo{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = getInput();


    printPhone(convertToDigit(s));
  }   

 public static String getInput() { 
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      String s1 = "";
      boolean length = false;
      while (length==false){ 
        System.out.println(" Please enter a telephone number in this format ###-AAA-AAAA") ;
         s1 = scan.nextLine();
        if(s1.length() != 12 ){
          System.out.println( "this is an invalid choice try again Plz..."); 
           length = false;

        }
        else{ 
          length = true; 
        }
      }
      return s1; 
    }

 public static String convertToDigit(String s010){
    s010 = s010.toLowerCase();
    String s001= s010.substring(0,3);
    String s002 = s010.substring(4,6);
    String s003 = s010.substring(8,12);
    String s1 = (s001+s002+s003);
    String s2 = "";

    // Exceptions to our problem to stop invalid inputs 
    if (s1 == null) {
      System.out.print (" invalid input null thing"); 
    }
    if (s1.length() != 10){
      System.out.print (" invalid input"); 
    }

    String s6 = "";
    for (int i=0; i < s1.length(); i++) {


      if (Character.isDigit(s1.charAt(i))){
        s2 += s1.charAt(i); 
      }

      //sorting of the letter inputs 
      char ch = s1.charAt(i); 

      if (ch == 'a'||ch=='b'||ch== 'c'){
        s2 += "2"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'd'||ch=='e'||ch=='f'){
        s2 += "3"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'g'||ch=='h'||ch=='i'){
        s2 += "4"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'j'||ch=='k'||ch=='l'){
        s2 += "5"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'm'||ch=='n'||ch=='o'){
        s2 += "6"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'p'||ch=='q'||ch=='r'|| ch=='s'){
        s2 += "7"; 
      }
      if (ch == 't'||ch=='u'||ch=='v'){
        s2 += "8"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'w'||ch=='x'||ch=='y'|| ch=='z')
      {
        s2 += "9"; 
      }
      else{ 
      }

     String s3 = s2.substring(0,3);
    String s4 = s2.substring(3,6);
    String s5 = s2.substring(6);
     s6 = ( s3 +"-"+ s4 + "-"+ s5);
    }

    return s6; 
    }

    public static void printPhone(String message) { //print out whatever string it is given, basically System.out.println(), but through a method instead
    System.out.println(message);
  }
}
```

Not sure about how much more detail i can put into this.

Comment: If your TA can't debug a StringOutofBounds then you are in deep trouble... btw: We really don't care about your dinner.

Comment: as the length is `12` and indexes are zero based, then `String s003 = s010.substring(8,12);` will fail

Comment: @John3136 *We really don't care about your dinner.* Speak for yourself, I am really hungry

Comment: @ScaryWombat Shouldn't wombats be asleep now? Perhaps that's you're problem (unless you are a rare North American Wombat ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found your problem.

In the method for converting input to digits, you wrote this:

```
String s6 = "";
for (int i=0; i < s1.length(); i++) {

  if (Character.isDigit(s1.charAt(i))){
    s2 += s1.charAt(i); 
  }

  //sorting of the letter inputs 
  char ch = s1.charAt(i); 

  if (ch == 'a'||ch=='b'||ch== 'c'){
    s2 += "2"; 
  }
  if (ch == 'd'||ch=='e'||ch=='f'){
    s2 += "3"; 
  }
  if (ch == 'g'||ch=='h'||ch=='i'){
    s2 += "4"; 
  }
  if (ch == 'j'||ch=='k'||ch=='l'){
    s2 += "5"; 
  }
  if (ch == 'm'||ch=='n'||ch=='o'){
    s2 += "6"; 
  }
  if (ch == 'p'||ch=='q'||ch=='r'|| ch=='s'){
    s2 += "7"; 
  }
  if (ch == 't'||ch=='u'||ch=='v'){
    s2 += "8"; 
  }
  if (ch == 'w'||ch=='x'||ch=='y'|| ch=='z')
  {
    s2 += "9"; 
  }
  else{ 
  }

 String s3 = s2.substring(0,3);
 String s4 = s2.substring(3,6);
 String s5 = s2.substring(6);
 s6 = ( s3 +"-"+ s4 + "-"+ s5);
}
```

Firstly, you have checked whether there are already any digit in the input string - if there is any, then you simply added the digit to processed string. Then you checked for letters and treated each letter accordingly.

But then you have a problem. Before completing construction of the processed string `s2` (within the `for` loop), you tried to extract parts of your processed string. This should be done after the `for` loop.

So, the method should look something like this.

```
 public static String convertToDigit(String s010){
    s010 = s010.toLowerCase();
    String s001= s010.substring(0,3);
    String s002 = s010.substring(4,6);
    String s003 = s010.substring(8,12);
    String s1 = (s001+s002+s003);
    String s2 = "";

    // Exceptions to our problem to stop invalid inputs 
    if (s1 == null) {
      System.out.print (" invalid input null thing"); 
    }
    if (s1.length() != 10){
      System.out.print (" invalid input"); 
    }

    String s6 = "";
    for (int i=0; i < s1.length(); i++) {


      if (Character.isDigit(s1.charAt(i))){
        s2 += s1.charAt(i); 
      }

      //sorting of the letter inputs 
      char ch = s1.charAt(i); 

      if (ch == 'a'||ch=='b'||ch== 'c'){
        s2 += "2"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'd'||ch=='e'||ch=='f'){
        s2 += "3"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'g'||ch=='h'||ch=='i'){
        s2 += "4"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'j'||ch=='k'||ch=='l'){
        s2 += "5"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'm'||ch=='n'||ch=='o'){
        s2 += "6"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'p'||ch=='q'||ch=='r'|| ch=='s'){
        s2 += "7"; 
      }
      if (ch == 't'||ch=='u'||ch=='v'){
        s2 += "8"; 
      }
      if (ch == 'w'||ch=='x'||ch=='y'|| ch=='z')
      {
        s2 += "9"; 
      }
      else{ 
      }

// They should not be here
/*   String s3 = s2.substring(0,3);
    String s4 = s2.substring(3,6);
    String s5 = s2.substring(6);
     s6 = ( s3 +"-"+ s4 + "-"+ s5);*/
    } // end of for loop; completed constructing s2

// They should be here
String s3 = s2.substring(0,3);
String s4 = s2.substring(3,6);
String s5 = s2.substring(6);
s6 = ( s3 +"-"+ s4 + "-"+ s5);

return s6; 
}
```

Comment: If this is indeed the problem, it would have been easier to spot with correct indentation. It sounds like a likely explanation.

Comment: This is probably the biggest explanation behind the problem. Another explanation is also provided in the question's comments as well.